# Debian/Armel: Missing usbserial-driver

Tags: debian, driver

I am looking for the usbserial driver: “option” for Debian Jessie and armel architecture.

Is there a package that contains this and other usbserial drivers?

Where is the source-code for this driver located?

Comment: this should probably be asked at [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @umläute I'd say it's borderline since it involves source code.

Comment: @Tshepang i don't see any :-)

Comment: @umläute that's cuz it's invisible, which does not imply absence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the kernel. Assuming you are building your own kernel, enable it by selecting it from a menu, which is presented after running `make menuconfig`:

```
Device Drivers
--> USB support
    ...
    --> USB Serial Converter support
```